# Why adjusted R2 score performs better than R2 score?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

One difference found on Goggle is
R2 assumes that every single variable explains the variation in the dependent variable.

The adjusted R2 tells you the percentage of variation explained by only the independent variables that actually affect the dependent variable.

Can you guys explain with example, so that it will be easy to understand.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Which is better R2 or adjusted R2?**
Adjusted R2 is the better model when you compare models that have a different amount of variables. The logic behind it is, that R2 always increases when the number of variables increases.
Meaning that even if you add a **useless variable** to you model, your R2 will still increase.